# Final interview without experience on responsibilities of the role

Tags: interviewing, work-experience, software-development, developer, skills

I applied for a software developer job in a big retailer company and the main responsibilities of the role is to work on an e-commerce/m-commerce mobile application.

I do not have any experience in working with an e-commerce project in my 5 year development career, though during my first interview, I did highlight some of my projects that were close or had some features that are similar to what an e-commerce app does. Surprisingly, I got called up for a final interview. After my first interview, I thought that I wouldn't be shortlisted as they were looking for someone who can work with their team in the project.

How should I approach my final interview with the general manager? Should I highlight that even if I do not have e-commerce experience that I would still be a great fit for the role as I am willing to learn and add e-commerce experience in my career?

Any advice on how I can stand out assuming most of my competition have more e-commerce experience than me and I have none.

Answer (score 1):

If you survived the first interview without this experience and were invited back for a final interview then this employer has already accepted the fact that you don't have that experience.   Some employer's attitude is 'Forget what you know, we'll teach you how WE do things', and maybe this is one of them.

Recommend just presenting well what you do have, and demonstrate the soft skills that you are open to learning what they have to teach as well as the usual stuff like being responsible, showing up on time, etc.

Good luck.